# How can I get this value to 2 decimal places?

Tags: excel, sum, decimal, vba

dub = Application.Sum(wb.Sheets("Sheet1").range("A:A"))

I have tried .numberformat "0.00" and setting the variable type as double with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the `Round` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
dub = Round(Application.Sum(wb.Sheets("Sheet1").range("A:A")),2)
```

Round(number, precision) function rounds numbers according to the specified precision.

Hope I have helped you!